# install selenium via command or website?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I need help with knowing whether the best way to install selenium is via command line on Mac, or via the selenium website. Same for chrome or IE.exe, should that be installed via command line or the actual website?
If you recommend installing via the website how would that work out for running tests via CI (Jenkins) on other machines - we would practically need to install selenium/ or browser.exe on every machine right? Which is why I thought it may make more sense to install all this via command line.
Either way, any opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You can't run exe files on Mac. Probably not via a Jenkins Linux machine either

Answer (score 0):

1) For run by Jenkins, the better way it's to setup a selenium grid follow guide: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2

with seleniu grid, you not need to setup selenium on each jenkins salve. because
grid will supply browser machine for your test.

2) For run/debug on local, i recommend a way to setup selenium and chrome.exe/IE.exe by webdriver-manager, which is a Nodejs package. 
so you need to install NodeJS firstly. 
  a. install nodejs:https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#macos 
  b. execute 'npm install -g webdriver-manager' in terminal 
  c. execute 'npm config get preifx', it will print out a path in terminal 
  d. export above path in PATH environment 
  e. execute 'webdriver-manager version' to check PATH evnrionment work as expect

3) the command to install selenium stuffs like: 
webdriver-manager update --verions.standalone=3.4.0  --versions.chrome=2.30  --versions.ie=

or just  webdriver-manager update , this will install latest version of selenium server jar and chromedriver.exe for chrome and geckodriver.exe for firefox.

A reminder: latest version may not compatible with your local browser. so I think you need use options:  --versions.xxxx=xxxxx to install certain version.

if latest version not caompatible with your local browser, and you want to start a selenium server, you also need to append the versions options like used in update:

webdriver-manager start --versions.chome=xxxxx (if you need run with chrome)
--versions.gecko=xxxx (if run with firefox) --version.ie=xxxx (if run with ie)

all avaiable options you can get by execute  webdriver-manager help as below:
[image]
[image]

webdriver-manager update --ie
[image: webdriver-manager update --ie]

Comment: 1. Do I need to install webdriver-manager only, or also selenium standalone server, and ‘webdriver’ by itself?
2. How to export above path in PATH env?
3. whats the best way to install chrome/IE/Firefox.exe. Is it to type ‘webdriver-manager update’?
4. Is there any particular folder where all this will be installed - do I need to know that location for any purpose?
5. what do you suggest is the best way to install selenium and all the browser.exe. via command line or via the website? i dunno the benefit so I am wondering
Really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: 1. yes, only install nodejs and webdrive-manager only, after that you can install selenium standalone serand and webdirver.exe by execute command: webdriver-manager update --ie --chrome --gecko --edge (this will install latest version of them).  2. for windows modify the enviroment variable:PATH, for linux and mac google search how to modify PATH;

Comment: 3.  best way to install is to find out  the version of selenium standalone server/ chromedriver.exe /firefoxdriver.exe/ iedriver.exe which capatible with your local browser, after thant instal them by command: webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone=xxxx  --versions=chrome=xxx --versions.gecko=xxxx --versions.ie=xxxx  (if you only want to install chromedriver.exe,  just to use ---versions.chrome=xxxx, similar way for other);

Comment: If you just execute 'webdriver-manager update'  without any parameters only standalone server,  chrome and firefox webdriver's latest verions be installed, no IE webdriver;

Comment: 4. all things should be install webdriver-manager/selenium folder,  how to know where is webdriver-manager folder, it's simple to execute command 'npm config get prefix', it will return a  folder path, navigate into that folder and you will found webdriver-manager under  node_modules folder.   5. the best way to install all things from command line had mentioned in reply for question 2 and 4.

Comment: install from website, you have to download one by one and  the start command every time if the version change, use webdriver-manager to start server, it's simly to execute 'webdriver-manager start'  to use latest version, or append parameter --versions.standalone=xxx --versions.chrome=xxx to use certain version,  you can  use --versions.xxxx to control any version to want to start server, even there are many versions installed;  Finally, Take Action, not to ask a lot before any practice. You can learn more and found the answer of your above question by pratice in person.

Comment: thanks @yong just out of curiosity..how long have you been using Selenium for? I'm assuming you use Java..

Comment: about 2 years,  I use selenium + java and Protractor + Javascript both.

Comment: 1. whenever I try webdriver-manager update --ie --chrome --gecko --edge command..it always install only chrome, standalone, and firefox. Even if I try only webdriver-manager update --ie...it still installs only chrome/firefox/standalone. can you advise?
Also how should I know which version specifically of chrome or IE or firefox I need to install..where can i check that? Thanks

2. If I go to usr/local/lib/node_modules...all the folders of nom and selenium web driver are there...is that my PATH?

Comment: the command worked well on my machine,  please see the last screenshot in my answer above.  Which version is your webdriver-manager? I think your version is close to latest, so it shouldn't fail on your command. How about try webdriver-manager update --versions.ie=3.5.1 or --versions.ie=latest

Comment: Here are the steps I followed

Comment: Here are the steps I followed
1. npm install -g selenium-server
2. npm install -g seleniuv-webdriver
3. npm install -g webdriver-manager
4. If i go to /usr/local/lib/node_modules...under there I have 4 folders 'npm', 'selenium-server', 'seleniuv-webdriver', 'webdriver-manager'.

5. I ran webdriver-manager help command but it did not show anything about IE or edge
6. I tried 'webdriver-manager update --version IE' but it still only installs selenium server, chrome driver, and geckodriver (COULD IT BE BECAUSE I DO NOT HAVE IE or EDGE Browser installed on my MAC?

Comment: You get the point.  I get a MAC to practice the command, get the same result as you.  webdriver-manager is smart. it disable the related things about IE. chrome and firefox worked well.

Comment: so please tell me
1. On MAC there is no way for me to test for IE?
2. I did 'npm install -g selenium-server', 'npm install -g selenium-webdriver', and 'npm install -g webdriver-manager'. Do I need to install all of that or only the webdriver-manager. Whats the difference?
Thanks!

Comment: 1. I think you can't install IE on a MAC, so you can't test IE locally. But you can    run script on a remote IE by use selenium server or grid.  2. you only need to npm install  -g webdriver-manager, then use webdriver-manager to install selenium-server-stanadalone.jar,  webdriver.exe for browsers.

Comment: if you plan to use javascript to write auto script, you can install selenum-webdriver which is Selenium Client API of Javascript implement.  there are other library for different language like for java, python, ruby. It dependent which language you choose for auto script.

Comment: webdriver-manager is only a tool to help you install/update selenium-server-standalone.jar and webdriver.exe,  and help to you start a selenium server.  it's not include any seleium client API, like clic(), sendKeys(), getText().

Comment: So two things
1. Am I still required to do 'npm install -g selenium-server' and 'npm install -g selenium-webdriver', or just npm install -g webdriver-manager' is enough?

2. If i go to /usr/local/lib/node_modules...under there I have 4 folders 'npm', 'selenium-server', 'seleniuv-webdriver', 'webdriver-manager'. How do I need to set for my env. PATH variable?
THANKS!

Comment: only need to do 'npm install -g webdriver-manager' , then use webdriver-manager udpate to install selenium-standalone-server.jar and webdriver for vary browsers.   Did you see the introduce of each pakcage, it said clear the purpose of above 3 packages.

Comment: OK thanks. so nice I also did 'npm install -g selenium-server' and 'npm install -g selenium-webdriver'..should I remove the folders  'selenium-server', 'seleniuv-webdriver'...only keep the 'webdriver-manager' folder?

Also please answer the question about env. PATH variable

Comment: If you choose to use 'webdriver-manager' to install and start selenium server, 'selnium-server' can be removed.

Comment: For env PATH variable question,  use my Windows machine as example, after execute  npm config get prefix  in CLI,  it print out c:\tool\npm-global , (You should can find webdriver-manager.cmd under c:\tool\npm-global),    For windows  Start Menu -> Computer -> Right Click Menu -> Manage -> Enviroment Variables -> User Variables,   If there is already PATH variable , click edit button and append  ;c:\tool\npm-global; to the end of PATH value, if not, click new button, input PATH in name textbox and input  ;c:\tool\npm-global; in value textbox. (Please use semicolon as seperator)

Comment: I am having a problem. I installed all the stuff just like you said. However after that when on the command line I type 'chrome driver --version' I get chromedriver: command not found
Please help!

Comment: there is no a command `chrome driver` in those stuff, could you tell me what you want to archive when you try the command `chrome driver --version` , then I look into if I can give you an answer.